# JSF view parameter fails when accessing method defined with generics

Tags: jsf-2

I have uncovered some strange behavior trying to set a value with a view parameter.  The code below does NOT work...upon submission of the form with the view parameter, the id value is NOT set.  However, if the comments are removed from the getId and setId methods, the id value IS properly set.  Is there some issue with JSF EL when accessing generics, or am I doing something terribly wrong?  Can anyone explain this behavior?

Interestingly, I receive no exceptions...the value is simply not set. In fact, the setId method in the abstract class is not even called.

```
public abstract class AbstractBusinessObjectAction<E, ID extends    Serializable>  {

  protected abstract BusinessObjectManager<E, ID> getBusinessObjectManager();

  public  ID getId() {
    ID id = getBusinessObjectManager().getId();
    return id;
  }

  public void setId(final ID id) {
    getBusinessObjectManager().setId(id);
  }
}


@Named("configuration")
@ConversationScoped
public class ConfigurationAction extends AbstractBusinessObjectAction<ConfigurationParameter, Long> {

  @Inject
  private ConfigurationParameterManager manager;

  protected BusinessObjectManager<ConfigurationParameter, Long> getBusinessObjectManager() {
    return manager;
  }

//  public Long getId() {
//    Long id = super.getId();
//    return id;
//  }

//  public void setId(Long id) {
//    super.setId(id);
//  }
}
```

Following is an except from the .xhtml:

```
<f:metadata>
    <f:viewParam id="entityIdParam" name="entityId" value="#{configuration.id}"  />
</f:metadata>
```

Comment: maybe it's because the viewParam is a String, and maybe it can't be parsed to ID, but it can be parsed to Long, that's why it works when you uncomment getters/setters; though I think it should be throwing some exception..

Comment: What JSF and appserver impl/version are you using? I can't reproduce your problem with Mojarra 2.1.7 on Tomcat 7.0.27.

Comment: I am using JBoss 7.1.1.Final, default standalone configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a converter solved the problem.

```
<f:viewParam id="entityIdParam" name="entityId" value="#{configuration.id}" >
  <f:converter converterId="javax.faces.Long" />
</f:viewParam>
```

To the best of my knowledge, this is the reason:

Because the id property is of type `ID extends Serializable` in the abstract class, JSF tries to install a non-existant Serializable converter.  The reason the code works when I uncomment the methods indicated, is that JSF properly detects that it needs a `javax.faces.Long` converter based on the explicit declaration of `Long` on the property methods for the "id" property.

Thanks to @Damian for the tip!